# Rails: cache with substitutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fragment-caching, rack-cache

I have a partial I am caching, but one part of it is dynamic:

```
- cache @product do
  .product
    #.....
    .price = format_money(@product.money)
```

And would like to turn it into something like this:

```
- cache_subst @product, {price: format_money(@product.money)} do
  .product
    #.....
    .price {{price}}
```

Is there some gem or method that does this?

**Update:**

Please don't suggest making money part of the key in any way, thats what we're doing right now.

Comment: I assume the value for `money` method comes from some associated model?

Comment: `money` returns money object which is then converted to the viewer's currency

Answer (score 0):

Since the variability of the cached view is the currency, and there is a limited number of currencies, I think the best strategy would be to add the currency to the cache key:

```
- cache [@product, format_money(@product.money)] do
  .product
    #....
    .price = format_money(@product.money)
```

Comment: Thats what we're doing now and what we're trying to avoid by having a substitution in our template.

Comment: Why is that problematic?

Comment: It works but we simply want to avoid it. One of the drawbacks is that for every currency it will eat more cache, the more important one is that currency exchange changes and as things are cached at different time the thumbnail can show different price than the product/show.